How to create a symbol that wasn't there before？
How do I write this symbol in LateX，This symbol indicates some kind of connection between the two objects，I have absolutely no idea how to write it on latex because it's a brand new symbol，This is a picture of the symbol：

This question is similar to: How to look up a symbol or identify a letter from a math alphabet or other character?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I'm not finding that symbol in the Comprehensive guide, nor with Detexify.  Am I looking in the wrong place?  If it's not there, then how does the proposed duplicate apply?

One approach using the \AC symbol of the wasysym package to construct this "looking you" symbol. It works almost well with any font size  with the default font. With other fonts could need some tuning (e.g., with DejaVu Serif you will obtain a funny "roll eyes" version).

\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm,a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newlength{\charwidth}
\newlength{\charheight}
\def\lookyou{%
\settowidth{\charwidth}{\ensuremath\AC}
\settowidth{\charheight}{\ensuremath\AC}
\mathop% ???
{\resizebox{\charwidth}{.5\charheight}{%%%
\cdot\kern-.5\charwidth%%%
\rotatebox[origin=c]{-12}{\AC}%%%
\kern-1.06\charwidth%%%%
\reflectbox{%%%%
\rotatebox[origin=c]{-12}{\AC}}%%%%
\kern-.5\charwidth \cdot %%%%
}}}

\begin{document}
\tiny \[A \lookyou B\]  
\scriptsize \[A \lookyou B\] 
\footnotesize \[A  \lookyou B \]
\small \[A  \lookyou B \] 
\normalsize \[A  \lookyou B \] 
\large \[A  \lookyou B \] \newpage
\Large \[A  \lookyou B \]
\huge \[A  \lookyou B \]
\Huge \[A  \lookyou B \]
\end{document}


Clipped \sim and reflected copy thereof; then stretched a bit, with dots added in the middle.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\box_new:N \l__shichen_symbol_a_box
\box_new:N \l__shichen_symbol_b_box
\dim_new:N \l__shichen_symbol_trim_dim

\NewDocumentCommand{\strange}{}{\mathrel{\shichen_symbol:}}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \shichen_symbol:
 {
  \group_begin:
  \hbox_set:Nn \l__shichen_symbol_a_box { $\use:c{m@th}\sim$ }
  \hbox_set:Nn \l__shichen_symbol_b_box { $\use:c{m@th}\sim$ }
  \dim_set:Nn \l__shichen_symbol_trim_dim { 0.2\box_wd:N \l__shichen_symbol_a_box }
  \box_scale:Nnn \l__shichen_symbol_b_box { -1 } { 1 }
  \box_set_trim:Nnnnn \l__shichen_symbol_a_box
   { \l__shichen_symbol_trim_dim } % left
   { 0pt } % bottom
   { \l__shichen_symbol_trim_dim } % right
   { 0pt} % top
  \box_set_trim:Nnnnn \l__shichen_symbol_b_box
   { \l__shichen_symbol_trim_dim } % left
   { 0pt } % bottom
   { \l__shichen_symbol_trim_dim } % right
   { 0pt} % top
  \box_set_clipped:N \l__shichen_symbol_a_box
  \box_set_clipped:N \l__shichen_symbol_b_box
  \box_scale:Nnn \l__shichen_symbol_a_box { 1.2 } { 1 }
  \box_scale:Nnn \l__shichen_symbol_b_box { 1.2 } { 1 }
  \ooalign
   {
    \box_use:N \l__shichen_symbol_a_box
    \cr
    \hidewidth
    $\use:c{m@th}\vcenter
     {
      \hbox_to_wd:nn { 1.1\box_wd:N \l__shichen_symbol_a_box }
       { $\scriptscriptstyle{\cdot}\hss{\cdot}$ }
     }
    $
    \hidewidth
    \cr
    \box_use:N \l__shichen_symbol_b_box
   }
  \group_end:
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$A \strange B$

\end{document}


A possible alternative:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\strange}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\strange@\relax}}
\newcommand{\strange@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-30}{$\m@th#1\sim$}}%
  \sbox\tw@{\reflectbox{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-30}{$\m@th#1\sim$}}}%
\dimen@=\wd\tw@
  \raisebox{0pt}[0.85\height][0pt]{%
    \ooalign{
      \hfil$\m@th#1\mkern-1.7mu\nonscript\mkern-0.5mu$\box\z@\hfil\cr
      \hidewidth\hbox to \wd\tw@{%
        \hskip 0pt plus 1.2fil
        $\m@th#1\cdot$%
        \hss
        $\m@th#1\cdot$%
        \hskip 0pt plus 2fil
      }\hidewidth\cr
      \hfil\box\tw@\hfil\cr
    }%
  }%
  \mkern-1.1mu
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\fboxsep=0pt\fboxrule=0.1pt
X\fbox{$\strange$}X

$A\strange B_{\strange}$

\end{document}


